# xpages display an alert window while users trying to access fields and doc. being in read mode

Tags: xpages

Testing a XPiNC and on browser application, some users would like if it's possible to display some pop-up / alert window when they try to complete some fields and the document is `!currentDocument.isEditable()`.

The main document structure lays in a Xpages, and there are numerous fields, some of them having `showReadonlyAsDisabled="true"`, some of them not.

so, the users when they'll open an existing document, they even can not access the fields, they are just clicking on the xpage. Is it possible to display some message / alert window? Is this task in a relationship with the fields from the xpage or with some event of it?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What does " when they try to complete some fields" mean if the fields are not editable? Do you want a way to display an alert if the user clicks on the web page?

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten: yes, the fields are not editable, but the fields margins are visible, and maybe some users are trying to adding some values to those fields, without knowing the fact that the document is in read mode in that moment. And yes, I would like to display an alert if the user clicks on the web page, but only if !currentDocument.isEditable().

Comment: I suggest you change the UI then to make it clear for the users that they are only reading and not editing - for instance by removing the showReadonlyAsDisabled option so that the fields doesn't look like fields.

Comment: Another suggestion would be to display a message such as a bootstrap style alert at the top of your form indicating that it is read only.  For example: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts

Comment: @MichaelG.Smith it seems OK for my required task. Could you give me a simple example on how to achive this? Showing a bootstrap alert when the users click inside a doc. being in readonly mode

Comment: I'd go back to the main point. If the fields are not editable, why are you confusing the user by making them appear to be editable? I'd suggest that it's a bad user experience and will make them dislike your application. Of course, if management insists on you making your application unfriendly in this way, you have little choice.

Comment: @DavidNavarre thanks for your observation and for your answer, too. The management suggest me friendly if I can achieve this task, just to see "how it goes". I told them that it wouldn't be a great idea and we will see the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple solution is to display a div with a message inside if the document is in read mode. Here's a simple example:

```
<xp:div rendered="#{javascript:!document.isEditable()}">
    The document is readonly.
</xp:div>
```

If you use OneUI you can style it as a [proper OneUI info message](http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/oneui/2.1/docPublic/components/messages.htm) :-)

```
<xp:div rendered="#{javascript:!document.isEditable()}" styleClass="lotusMessage lotusConfirm">
    <xp:image id="Icon" url="/.ibmxspres/domino/oneuiv2/images/iconInfo16.png"></xp:image>
    The document is readonly.
</xp:div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to try checking server side, as you don't want to go through the refresh cycle, even though !currentDocument.isEditable() is usable there....

1. First, I'd recommend not using showReadonlyAsDisabled, since it encourages the confusion you're trying to avoid.
2. If that's not an option, then instead of trying to determine if the underlying document is editable, you can start your search for solutions by checking the values of the HTML component. Unfortunately, the value of disabled is **false** when a control is read only being displayed as disabled. You might be able to find a method that works for you on the client side using that. I struggled in attempts in onclick and onkeypress.

   XSP.getElementById("myInputText").disabled
3. You might want to simply have two controls - one for edit mode and one for read mode, with onkeypress in edit mode returning

   XSP.alert("You cannot edit this field")

Of course, since you can try typing in the disabled field even when it's in edit mode, why not **always** pop that alert?